# WP custom logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a custom logout page using templates (you know, creating simple pages and adding them "/* Template Name: MyTemplate */"). This way I can access all wp core features:

```
<?php /*Template Name: My Logout */
    wp_logout();
?>
```

The problem is when I call this template using Ajax I'm getting the same warning:

> **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /XXX/mylogout.php:1) in **/XXX/wp-includes/pluggable.php** on line **697**

Yes it's a warning but the logout action is not done (if I try to access member page, I can without log in).

I'm have been reading about blank spaces in functions.php and similars but looks like all it's fine. Maybe "Template Name..." comment??

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a *logout* link with:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

where it will redirect you to the home page. You can replace it with a custom redirect page.

Check out the `wp_logout_url()` function in the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url).

Comment: It works @birgire!! Thank you very much. I was trying in a difficult way (using templates and jquery ajax) and your solution solves my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to check logout page on the `init` hook to avoid headers already sent error...

```
add_action('init', '_logout_func');

function _logout_func() {
   if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'logout'))
       wp_logout();
}
```